# Multi-dimensional Array in Ruby Shoes not working as expected

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to create a method to create a matrix and filled it with specific values but for some weird and unexpected reason the instructions marked as comments inside of the while loop won't work at all, what am I doing wrong? Here's the code:

```
def map(r,c)

    row = 0 #row counter
    map = Array.new

    while (row < r)

        map[row] = Array.new #Creates an array with row Rows

        col = 0 #col counter

        while (col < c)

            map[row][col] = 0 #Floor
            map[0][col]   = 1 #Top wall
            #map[r][col]   = 2 #Bottom wall
            map[row][0]   = 3 #Left wall
            map[row][c]   = 4 #Right wall
            map[0][0]     = 5 #Top left corner
            map[0][c]     = 6 #Top right corner
            #map[r][0]     = 7 #Bottom left corner
            #map[r][c]     = 8 #Bottom right corner

            col = col + 1
        end
        row = row + 1
    end
    alert(map)
end

Shoes.app(:width => 650,:height => 450) do
    map(17,22)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to assign a value to an array in ruby which is outside its bounds, the array is filled with `nil`s up to that point, and sets the value in the right location:

```
a = []
a[5] = 5
puts a
# => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 5]
```

if you try to get a value outside the bounds of the array, you get `nil`:

```
a = []
a[5]
# => nil
```

that is why when you try to assign `map[r][col] = 2` you get an error, since `map[r]` is `nil`.

To fix that, you need to pre-populate your `map` array with `r` empty arrays:

```
map = Array.new(r+1) { [] }
```

this way `map[r]` will not return `nil`, and you can set its values:

```
def map(r,c)

    row = 0 #row counter
    map = Array.new(r+1) { [] }

    while (row < r)

        col = 0 #col counter

        while (col < c)

            map[row][col] = 0 #Floor
            map[0][col]   = 1 #Top wall
            map[r][col]   = 2 #Bottom wall
            map[row][0]   = 3 #Left wall
            map[row][c]   = 4 #Right wall
            map[0][0]     = 5 #Top left corner
            map[0][c]     = 6 #Top right corner
            map[r][0]     = 7 #Bottom left corner
            map[r][c]     = 8 #Bottom right corner

            col = col + 1
        end
        row = row + 1
    end
    alert(map)
end

Shoes.app(:width => 650,:height => 450) do
    map(17,22)
end
```